# SQL Update query via AJAX issue with Syntax

Tags: php, mysql, sql, ajax

I have been banging my head against the wall for hours on something I would consider incredibly basic.

The query is meant to update a row based on an array - I dont feel I need to delve into what is going on here as it is very simple. The query being run is as follows:

```
$mysqli->query("UPDATE CMS SET 
order=" . intval($mysqli->real_escape_string($listingCounter)) . 
" WHERE id=" . intval($mysqli->real_escape_string($recordIDValue))) 
or die('Error, insert query failed :'.$mysqli->errno."
<br/> Error : '".$mysqli->error."'");
```

I have played around with intval purely because I felt it was a formatting error - the same with real_escape_string. But the error remains the same:

```
Error, insert query failed :1064
Error : 'You have an error in your SQL syntax; 
check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for 
the right syntax to use near 'order=1 WHERE id=6' at line 1'
```

I expect it is something hugely simple I have missed, but I cannot think of the issue. I am running MYSQL 5.5 and PHP 5.4 - ALSO this query is being run over AJAX - again, not sure this should have this sort of effect.

Any help would be much appreciated, thanks.

UPDATE:

MY DB TABLE is called CMS and the rows in question are ID (integer) and Order (integer)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `order` is a reserved word.  Wrap it in backquotes:

```
UPDATE CMS
    SET `order`=" . intval($mysqli->real_escape_string($listingCounter)) . "
    WHERE id=" . intval($mysqli->real_escape_string($recordIDValue))
```

Comment: Perfect - you are exactly right, much appreciated, I will mark your answer after the 10min mandatory wait. Thank you